# mqtt broker and kafka connect standalone

Tags: apache-kafka, mqtt, apache-kafka-connect

i want ingest data from mqtt broker(mosquitto) to kafka broker(apache kafka) , so i flow these steps

1/  I create my mqtt connector from evokly github : so i download the code and i use gradlew to build the project and generate .jar  dependencies (kafka-connect-mqtt-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar)
2/ i put .jar files into C:\kafka_2.13-2.8.0\connectors director
3/ after i add CLASSPATH  to system variable

[image: CLASSPATH variable]

4/
[image: this my mqtt.properties]
5/
[image: this my standalone.properties]
6/ i start zookeeper and server kafka
7/ i start kafka connect

```
.\bin\windows\connect-standalone  .\config\connect-standalone.properties  .\config\mqtt.properties
```

[image: kafka connect started with success]

8/
[image: this my mosquitto.conf]
9/ now when istart mosquitto and publish to mqtt topic
[image: mosquitto subscriber]
10/ nothing received into my kafka topic

[image: kafka consumer]

NB: when i publish and consume on mosquitto it works fine also when i produce on kafka and consume from kafka it works fine but with kafka connect no problem shown but i don't receive data any help please

this is logs

```
    [2021-07-29 17:17:21,844] INFO Kafka Connect standalone worker initial
    [2021-07-29 17:17:21,846] INFO Kafka Connect starting (org.apache.kafk
    [2021-07-29 17:17:21,851] INFO Herder starting (org.apache.kafka.conne
    [2021-07-29 17:17:21,853] INFO Worker starting (org.apache.kafka.conne
    [2021-07-29 17:17:21,856] INFO Starting FileOffsetBackingStore with fi
    [2021-07-29 17:17:21,867] INFO Worker started (org.apache.kafka.connec
    [2021-07-29 17:17:21,868] INFO Herder started (org.apache.kafka.connec
    [2021-07-29 17:17:21,870] INFO Initializing REST resources (org.apache
    [2021-07-29 17:17:21,993] INFO Adding admin resources to main listener
    [2021-07-29 17:17:22,214] INFO DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node
    [2021-07-29 17:17:22,216] INFO No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
    [2021-07-29 17:17:22,220] INFO node0 Scavenging every 600000ms (org.ec
    juil. 29, 2021 5:17:23 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Provide
AVERTISSEMENT: A provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resour
applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration probnored.
    juil. 29, 2021 5:17:23 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Provide
AVERTISSEMENT: A provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resourfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuratioe will be ignored.
    juil. 29, 2021 5:17:23 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Provide
    AVERTISSEMENT: A provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resourable in the SERVER runtime. 
    Due to constraint configuration problems t
    juil. 29, 2021 5:17:23 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Provide
AVERTISSEMENT: A provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resourlicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problem
    juil. 29, 2021 5:17:23 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors logErro
AVERTISSEMENT: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: Theource contains empty path annotation.
    WARNING: The (sub)resource method createConnector in org.apache.kafka.
    WARNING: The (sub)resource method listConnectors in org.apache.kafka.c
    WARNING: The (sub)resource method listConnectorPlugins in org.apache.k
    WARNING: The (sub)resource method serverInfo in org.apache.kafka.conne

    [2021-07-29 17:17:23,568] INFO Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1
    [2021-07-29 17:17:23,571] INFO REST resources initialized; server is s
    [2021-07-29 17:17:23,573] INFO Kafka Connect started (org.apache.kafka
    [2021-07-29 17:17:23,605] INFO AbstractConfig values:
 (org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig:372)
    [2021-07-29 17:17:23,638] INFO Creating connector mqtt of type com.evo
    [2021-07-29 17:17:23,641] INFO SourceConnectorConfig values:
        config.action.reload = restart
        connector.class = com.evokly.kafka.connect.mqtt.MqttSourceConn
        errors.log.enable = true
        errors.log.include.messages = true
        errors.retry.delay.max.ms = 60000
        errors.retry.timeout = 0
        errors.tolerance = none
        header.converter = null
        key.converter = null
        name = mqtt
        predicates = []
        tasks.max = 1
        topic.creation.groups = []
        transforms = []
        value.converter = null
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SourceConnectorConfig:372)
    [2021-07-29 17:17:23,649] INFO EnrichedConnectorConfig values:
        config.action.reload = restart
        connector.class = com.evokly.kafka.connect.mqtt.MqttSourceConn
        errors.log.enable = true
        errors.log.include.messages = true
        errors.retry.delay.max.ms = 60000
        errors.retry.timeout = 0
        errors.tolerance = none
        header.converter = null
        key.converter = null
        name = mqtt
        predicates = []
        tasks.max = 1
        topic.creation.groups = []
        transforms = []
        value.converter = null
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.ConnectorConfig$EnrichedConnectorCo
    [2021-07-29 17:17:23,696] INFO Instantiated connector mqtt with versioa.connect.runtime.Worker:284)
[2021-07-29 17:17:23,702] INFO Finished creating connector mqtt (org.a
[2021-07-29 17:17:23,705] INFO Start a MqttSourceConnector (com.evokly
[2021-07-29 17:17:23,707] INFO MqttSourceConnectorConfig values:
        kafka.topic = kafka-test
        message_processor_class = class com.evokly.kafka.connect.mqtt.
        mqtt.clean_session = true
        mqtt.client_id = null
        mqtt.connection_timeout = 30
        mqtt.keep_alive_interval = 60
        mqtt.password = xxxxxx
        mqtt.qos = 1
        mqtt.server_uris = tcp://localhost:1883
        mqtt.ssl.ca_cert = null
        mqtt.ssl.cert = null
        mqtt.ssl.key = null
        mqtt.topic = mqtt
        mqtt.user = null
 (com.evokly.kafka.connect.mqtt.MqttSourceConnectorConfig:372)
[2021-07-29 17:17:23,714] INFO Initialize transform process properties
[2021-07-29 17:17:23,714] INFO Initialize transform process properties[2021-07-29 17:17:23,714] INFO Initialize transform process properties
[2021-07-29 17:17:23,714] INFO Initialize transform process properties
(com.evokl
y.kafka.connect.mqtt.MqttSourceConnector:77)
[2021-07-29 17:17:23,719] INFO SourceConnectorConfig values:
[2021-07-29 17:17:23,714] INFO Initialize transform process properties
(c
om.evokly.kafka.connect.mqtt.MqttSourceConnector:77)
[2021-07-29 17:17:23,719] INFO SourceConnectorConfig values:
[2021-07-29 17:17:23,714] INFO Initialize transform process propertie
s                                                                    n
(com.evokly.kafka.connect.mqtt.MqttSourceConnector:77)
[2021-07-29 17:17:23,719] INFO SourceConnectorConfig values:
[2021-07-29 17:17:23,714] INFO Initialize transform process properties (com.evokly.kafka.connect.mqtt.MqttSourceConnector:77)
[2021-07-29 17:17:23,719] INFO SourceConnectorConfig values:
        config.action.reload = restart
        connector.class = com.evokly.kafka.connect.mqtt.MqttSourceConnector        errors.log.enable = true
        errors.log.include.messages = true
        errors.retry.delay.max.ms = 60000
        errors.retry.timeout = 0
        errors.tolerance = none
        header.converter = null
        key.converter = null
        name = mqtt
        predicates = []
        tasks.max = 1
        topic.creation.groups = []
        transforms = []
        value.converter = null
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SourceConnectorConfig:372)
[2021-07-29 17:17:23,724] INFO EnrichedConnectorConfig values:
        config.action.reload = restart
        connector.class = com.evokly.kafka.connect.mqtt.MqttSourceConnector        errors.log.enable = true        errors.log.include.messages = true
        errors.retry.delay.max.ms = 60000
        errors.retry.timeout = 0
        errors.tolerance = none        header.converter = null
        key.converter = null
        name = mqtt
        predicates = []
        tasks.max = 1
        topic.creation.groups = []        transforms = []
        value.converter = null
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.ConnectorConfig$EnrichedConnectorConfig:372)
```

mosquitto log

```
    1627580533: mosquitto version 2.0.11 starting
1627580533: Using default config.
1627580533: Starting in local only mode. Connections will only be possible from clients running on this machine.
1627580533: Create a configuration file which defines a listener to allow remote access.
1627580533: For more details see https://mosquitto.org/documentation/authentication-methods/
1627580533: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1627580533: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1627580533: mosquitto version 2.0.11 running
1627588404: New connection from ::1:57594 on port 1883.
1627588404: New client connected from ::1:57594 as auto-9C24C5D0-B74D-9EC0-49FE-B4EA2A55272E (p2, c1, k60).
1627588404: No will message specified.
1627588404: Sending CONNACK to auto-9C24C5D0-B74D-9EC0-49FE-B4EA2A55272E (0, 0)
1627588404: Received PUBLISH from auto-9C24C5D0-B74D-9EC0-49FE-B4EA2A55272E (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'mqtt', ... (3 bytes))
1627588404: Received DISCONNECT from auto-9C24C5D0-B74D-9EC0-49FE-B4EA2A55272E
1627588404: Client auto-9C24C5D0-B74D-9EC0-49FE-B4EA2A55272E disconnected.
1627588938: New connection from ::1:57846 on port 1883.
1627588938: New client connected from ::1:57846 as auto-2798744F-5690-0500-211D-0EBD497E50F1 (p2, c1, k60).
1627588938: No will message specified.
1627588938: Sending CONNACK to auto-2798744F-5690-0500-211D-0EBD497E50F1 (0, 0)
1627588938: Received PUBLISH from auto-2798744F-5690-0500-211D-0EBD497E50F1 (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'mqtt', ... (3 bytes))
1627588938: Received DISCONNECT from auto-2798744F-5690-0500-211D-0EBD497E50F1
1627588938: Client auto-2798744F-5690-0500-211D-0EBD497E50F1 disconnected.
```

Comment: Please show files in the question itself, not external links. [help]

Comment: @OneCricketeer now i put images in question itself

Comment: Does this work for you ?  mosquitto_sub -h localhost -p 1883 -t mqtt

Comment: it works when i start mosquitto with this command : start mosquitto but when i start mosquitto with this command : net start mosquitto i must add -u user and -P password

Comment: Don't use images either. Please add the complete files. Some of us cannot access Imgur

Comment: Any errors in kafka-connect logs? Mosquito logs?

Comment: How do you start the kafka? How do you start the mosquitto? Are they on the same localhost?

Comment: yes in the same localhost but with different port : mosquitto :  127.0.0.1:1883 and kafka 127.0.0.9092

Comment: connector.class = com.evokly.kafka.connect.mqtt.MqttSourceConnector        errors.log.enable = true        errors.log.include.messages = true
This line doesn't look good, any information on the mosquitto logs? Can you share?

Comment: @RanLupovich kindly i update my post

Answer (score 0):

Add the following entry to your *mqtt.properties* file:

```
errors.log.enable=true
errors.log.include.messages=true
errors.tolerance=none
```

In addition, find the file *connect-log4j.properties* in your Kafka installation directory under /config and change this line:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, connectAppender
```

to:

```
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, stdout, connectAppender
```

You should get a lot of diagnostics information to help clarify the problem. If it does not clear up the issue, add the output to the question (Don't paste a screenshot, please. Copy the text output so we can search through the text)

Comment: when i add these two lines to mqtt.properties file kafka connect stopped

Comment: I fixed my answer - try the new settings

Comment: Edit your question and add the logs there. Make sure to mark the pasted text as code with the curly brackets '{}' tool so it will be more readable.

Comment: i think that the problem is on mosquitto broker

Comment: The log indicates that the Kafka Connector started but did not launch any task - so nothing it trying to actually connect to the MQTT broker. The problem is either the connector configuration or something in the connector code itself. Consider contacting the connector developer.

Comment: did you mean that the problem in jar files of connector so i must change my mqtt connector

Comment: Looks like it. From the code at: https://github.com/evokly/kafka-connect-mqtt/blob/master/src/main/java/com/evokly/kafka/connect/mqtt/MqttSourceTask.java#L63 - you should see that long line when a task starts. It's not there, so the connector is not actually starting the task and not even accessing mqtt. Contact the connecgtor developer for assistance.

Comment: have you any solution to correct this !! thank you in advance

Comment: Nothing more intelligent than reaching out to the developer of the connector on Github, or trying to debug the issue locally.