# Kafka Elastic search sink connector showing high CPU usage

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using elastic search sink connector in distributed mode(2 instance). With task of 8 and about 20 to 25 topics to be sink’ed to elastic search.

Even when there are no records to sink, the worker java process is showing 100% CPU usage using xmx(4GB).

The end to end transfer of records is happening properly, but high CPU usage is a concern.

Tried with various time related consumer settings (batch size, max poll interval) even enabled error tolerance with dead letter queue, none of them helped.

my settings:

```
 connector config
 {
    “name”: “elasticsearch-sink”,
    "config”: {
    “connector.class”: “io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector”,
    “tasks.max”: “8”,
    “topics.regex”:"(mytopics_\d+$)",
    “key.ignore”: “true”,
    “schema.ignore”: “true”,
    “connection.url”: “http://eshost:esport”,
    “type.name”: “kafka-connect”
}
}
```

Worker settings:

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9094,localhost:9095
group.id=test-cluster
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets
offset.storage.replication.factor=3
config.storage.topic=connect-configs
config.storage.replication.factor=3
status.storage.topic=connect-status
status.storage.replication.factor=3
status.storage.partitions=8
rest.port=9034
plugin.path=/pluginpath
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout
```

I’m trying it on a server grade setup (64GB RAM and 8 vCPU cores) and there is good connectivity to Kafka Broker as well as Elasticsearch server host.

Any pointers will help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration looks ok. There are two things you should try:

- Switch the topics regex to a static list of topics. Regex weirdness can often cause high CPU, so rule that out first.
- Raise the logging level of the connect workers - hopefully this will show you the culprit. Seem example of raising the logging level for connect workers here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68579044/1335661

Based on the log file you posted, the connect worker is polling the broker and receiving an immediate empty response, ignoring the timeout supplied. This is basically "busy-waiting" and is the cause of the high cpu usage.
In addition, the meta-data in the request header looks weird - the topic list is empty. It is possible that the Kafka connect internal topics have garbage in them. Try cleaning out these topics (https://docs.confluent.io/home/connect/userguide.html#kconnect-internal-topics) or with a fresh broker.

Comment: Thanks @Barak, I had tried using expanded topics using topics parameter just to rule it out, even tried with single topic. But was not helpful.

Comment: I submitted the previous comment very early:) 

Thanks for the log level link. 

I see lot of messages of this kind, Sending FETCH request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=FETCH, apiVersion=12, clientId=consumer-connect-cluster-test1-1, correlationId=304) and timeout 30000 to node 1001: FetchRequestData(clusterId=null, replicaId=-1, maxWaitMs=500, minBytes=1, maxBytes=52428800, isolationLevel=0, sessionId=1093868571, sessionEpoch=98, topics=[], forgottenTopicsData=[], rackId='') (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:522)
not able to understand which timeout is kicking in.

Comment: Post a sample of the log file in the question, it should make it easier to figure out.

Comment: One more thing: how many partitions per topic? Also, what is the version of the Kafka Broker and Kafka Connect worker?

Comment: Kafka version and connect worker both are using 2.7.0. my topics of interest have 8 partitions each. Kafka Connect related topics have recommended partitions(config-1, offset -25, status - 8).

Comment: have put a small log file here http://codepad.org/8eHTQHWS (lot repeats)